# Problemas con RedirectToaction in ApiRest en c#

Tags: c#, api, rest, asp.net-web-api, restful

estoy generando un ApiRest con c# y probandolo con PostMan

He realizado correctamente el Get(ALL)/ Get(Selected) y el Post(CreateOne)

ahora estoy intentando que el Post(CreateOne) en vez de devolverme el result con true o false, que me haga un redirectToAction al Get(selected) pero siempre me redirige al Get(ALL)

Algun consejo?

Aqui os dejo fotos con el codigo y los pasos que realizo a ver si veis mi fallo, muchas gracias:

Estado de la Api al empezar: --> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Post con PostMan: -->[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Recepcion del Post en la Api y intento de Redirect: -->
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

"Muestra" de donde hace realmente el redirect: -->
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tengo un problema: soy daltónico, por lo que me es totalmente imposible ver el código en las imágenes que has puesto. En lugar de imágenes lo adecuado es poner el código, ya que esta es una web sobre código no sobre imágenes. Además el código tiene la ventaja de que puedes hacer búsquedas de texto, cosa que no puedes hacer sobre una imagen.

Comment: @CharlesMarch es importante realices tus preguntas agregando el código como texto y no como imagen, saludos.

Comment: Ok perdonar, para las proximas publicaciones pondre solo el codigo, modificar esta ahora mismo me es imposible

Answer (score -2, accepted):

El problema era como estaba generando el `ActionResult`

mi funcion `Get(Selected)` dice:

```
// GET: api/Contact/5 
[HttpGet("{id}", Name = "Get")] public
ActionResult<ContactDTO> Get(int id)
```

entonces tenía que crear el `ActionResult`, para dirigirlo al metodo `GET` y pasarle el parámetro, como un nuevo parámetro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]